# How to highlight active nav tab in specific case

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am using [this](http://www.itworld.com/article/2832973/development/setting-an-active-menu-item-based-on-the-current-url-with-jquery.html) as a template for JS which selects proper nav using JQuery, with [this](http://api.jquery.com/category/manipulation/class-attribute/) API reference.

My current code:

index.php

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>ChillSpot Alpha 1.2.3</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="common/style.css">

        <script type="text/javascript" src="common/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="background.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="common/navHighlight.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript"> $( document ).ready( getImage );</script>
        <script type="text/javascript"> $( document ).ready( setNavigation );</script>
    </head>

<?php
    include 'common/header.html';
?>
//More code, snipped from example: not relevant
```

common/navHighlight.js

```
<!--

function setNavigation() {
    var path = window.location.pathname;
    path = path.replace(/\/$/, "");
    path = decodeURIComponent(path);

    $(".menuList a").each(function () {
        var href = $(this).attr('href');
        if (path.substring(0, href.length) === href) {
            $(this).closest('li').removeClass('tab');
            $(this).closest('li').addClass('tab selected');
        }
    });
}

//-->
```

common/header.html

```
        <div class="menu">
            <ul class = "menuList">
                <li class="tab"><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
                <li class="tab"><a href="comm.php">Communications</a></li>
                <li class="tab"><a href="chillcraft/index.php">ChillCraft</a></li>
                <li class="tab"><a href="forum.php">Forum</a></li>
                <li class="tab"><a href="ud.php">Updates</a></li>
                <li class="tab"><a href="about.php">About</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>

        <div class="content">
```

... this isnt working. What is different in my situation that causes the example to fail? All "li" elements end up with class "tab", none have "tab selected".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is actually what's wrong, but I do notice that the href's in their example all start with `/` while yours do not. Relative pathing could be why yours isn't working.

So if you change your html to this you might be fine:

```
<div class="menu">
    <ul class = "menuList">
        <li class="tab"><a href="/index.php">Home</a></li>
        <li class="tab"><a href="/comm.php">Communications</a></li>
        <li class="tab"><a href="/chillcraft/index.php">ChillCraft</a></li>
        <li class="tab"><a href="/forum.php">Forum</a></li>
        <li class="tab"><a href="/ud.php">Updates</a></li>
        <li class="tab"><a href="/about.php">About</a></li>        
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: DOH! I've looked at most other things with more scrutiny, but i missed this one! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

My approach on these cases is as follows:

Add a unique id to each of your tabs (in addition to the class you already have)
On each specific file (index.php, common.php, forum.php, etc) create an object with your selected tab:

```
var selected = $('#forumTab');
```

Execute a function where you ensure to be removing the active class from all tabs and add it only to your current tab:

```
$('.tab').removeClass('active');
selected.addClass('active');
```

Comment: Could be a good approach, but generally it is preferred not to change the way it is done if what is wrong is a simple fix, see TMP's answer. Thanks for your contribution.